# inputting about 8mb of data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.

The first line of each test case contains three space-separated integers — N, x, and M .The second line contains N space-separated integers A1, A2, …, AN.

```
example:  
     2
    3 2 3
    1 2 3
    3 3 3 
    1 2 3
```

I am using this format for scanning the values but since the I/O file is about 8 mb , it is giving time limit exceeded at SPOJ.

```
t=int(input())
for k in range(0,t):
    n,x,m=(input().split())
    n=int(n)
    x=int(x)
    m=int(m)
    lst=[]
    lst=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Can any one provide me with the fastest way for scanning i/p

Comment: where is such input located? in a file? provided by hand by the user/input-redirected? What is the `time limit error`? Thrown by what/whom?

Comment: in a competitve programming problem

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the error during the parsing phase, not during the processing phase?

Comment: it is not kind of error but  i want a way to inputting faster

Comment: Except removing unnecessary code (e.g. `lst=[]`), I don't think there's much that can be improved

Answer (score 0):

8Mb of data is quite small - we regularly read in 1Gb of data (Using Pandas) - depending on the data conversion at the time - a load usually takes less than 30 seconds.

Try profiling your code - so you are sure (not guessing) where the bottle neck is.

How much memory do you have on your machine - as this will have an effect at some point ?